# what does frame rate index value of 15 means in AC4 sync frame?

Tags: audio, android-mediaplayer, codec, dolby, dolby-audio-api

We are parsing AC4 audio segment, in this while parsing sync frame we are getting 15 as frame rate index, but the maximum value of frame rate index is 13, so is there any meaning of 15 as frame rate index in AC4 sync frame